# Adding coordinate labels to vector grid lines using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling, grids-graticules

I would like to know how I can add coordinate labels to the gridlines, created by the "Create Grid" function in the "Vector->Research Tools" menu, in QGIS 3.18?

My goal here is to create a gradient map of a spider group's population density in each degree square of southern Africa (currently projected on EPSG:4326). I have created a composite shapefile with all the relevant countries up to, and including, Zambia. I have also generated a grid with 1 degree spacing, using the Create Grid function, and used the Count Points in Polygon to generate the gradients. However, there seems to be no option to add labels to this grid to indicate which lat/long the grid is located in.

Comment: This is perfectly possible within the print layout.

Comment: @Erik Thank you, I found the option in the "Item Properties" tab. However, it seems that for some reason the original vector gridlines that I created do not align up properly with any coordinates. There is now a mismatch between the grid created in the Print Layout menu and the Create Grid function.